# Changing the icon of particular node in jtree dynamically based on its index

Tags: java, swing, jtree, cellrenderer

My problem is like this:
I have a tree with root and 4 leafnodes.
I need to change icon of a particular node (say 2nd leaf node).
My algorithm is like this:
**step 1: Find index of the required node**
**Step2:Change its icon**

I am done with step 1,but strucked at step 2.

Please help me out....
Thank you all in advance....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am correctly understanding what you mean, you should have your answer in the link below. If you have the icon you want to change, just create an instance of the [DefaultTreeCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display) and go from there. You can also use different lines for collapsing and expanding. Follow the steps on the link I am providing from Oracle.

Comment: @mKorbel I saw your reply and i am working on it....But i am unable to get exact output what i require....

Comment: here you can find_out some valuable examples http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm, expanding this answer, maybe you are wrong, because there nobody made you job for you, only moving to correct dirrections,

Comment: [`TreeIconDemo2`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#eg) is a good example, too.